# Ubuntu equivalent to getch function from msvcrt

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

With Python on Windows, I have been making a game. However, this game requires the `msvcrt` module, which is only available on Windows. I need the function `msvcrt.getch()`. If I was to make it possible to run this game on Ubuntu, or any Linux computer in general, what module, if any, would I be able to use? I would be fine with it *not* working on a Linux, but I would really like to find out a way. Again, is there a module, or any tools I can use, to use the `msvcrt.getch` function on Ubuntu?

Comment: Didn't test it, but did you try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/getch ?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @MattDMo this isn't opinionated, just asks how to make a cross platform a windows feature.

Comment: @xvan Read my comment - I never said the question was opinionated. Recommendation questions are off-topic because they tend to attract opinionated **answers** and spam. The link I gave gives some good pointers on how to ask a good recommendation question - I suggest you (and the OP) read it.

Answer (score 3):

The library *msvcrs* is only available on Windows. If you want to use a release for Ubuntu, check *getch* function.

```
import getch
```

This function get the pressed-key in keyboard.

Hope it help!

Comment: 'import getch' does not work in Python 3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: ```pip install getch``` on your environment and try again.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, if necessary (as Luan Souza said above):

```
pip install getch
```

In your code:

```
try:
    from getch import getch, getche         # Linux
except ImportError:
    from msvcrt import getch, getche        # Windows
```

Answer (score -1):

Tested with a ATtila library on bullseye ( aarch64)
Comment Line with '# import msvcrt' before import getch and you must sudo apt-get install python3-unittest2 before